# How to represent header value and actual message in Byte Array Java?

Tags: java, c++, arrays, endianness

I need to make a byte array in which I will have header values initially and my actual message will come after the header values.

My header values will have - data center which is a string, client_id which is integer, pool_id which is also integer and data_count is also an integer.

And my actual message which will come after header values is - `hello world`

In my case, my header length may grow so I need to initialize that as a variable so that I can increase it later on as needed.

I am little bit confuse in how to use Byte Array here. How can I represent this in a byte array in network byte order so that c++ program can decode this out properly on ubuntu 12.04 machine?

Comment: Why do you think you need to make a byte array? Surely what you have to do is write bytes to a file or socket? Directly? in which case all you need is `DataOutputStream`.

Comment: @EJP good point. I can think of a few reasons though; 1. Using UDP packets, or 2. if the packet needs to be prefixed with a length field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Protocol Buffers](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) to represent the messages (header and content). It will handle the transformations between languages and different platforms. Also, it is providing room for further expansion and support for multiple message versions.

For your example you can define the message format like (eg. messageModel.proto):

```
package common; 

option java_package = "my.java.package";
option java_outer_classname = "MessageProto";

message MyMessage {
  optional string dataCenter = 1 [default = DEFAULT_DC];
  optional int64 clientId = 2;
  optional int64 poolId = 3;
  optional int64 dataCount = 4;
  optional string body = 5;
}
```

Then using the `protoc` compile like:

```
protoc -I src/java/ --java_out=src/java/ messageModel.proto
```

You will generate the transport objects and the utility classes to marshal them from one endpoint to another (representing different messages even). Please check the [java tutorial](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial) for more details.

To create a `MyMessage` from java you will be able to do something like:

```
MessageProto.MyMessage.Builder mb = MessageProto.MyMessage.newBuilder();
mb.setDataCenter("aDC");
mb.setClientId(12);
mb.setPoolId(14);
mb.setDataCount(2);
mb.setbody("hello world");
MessageProto.MyMessage message = mb.build();
```

To transform the message into a byte array, you will use: `message.toByteArray()`

If `C++/C` is your destination you will need to generate (from the same model) the `C` builders and objects too. And to decode the message you will do something like:

```
MessageProto.MyMessage message = MessageProto.MyMessage.parseFrom(buffer);
```

Where `buffer` will represent the received content.

If this is only a homework assignment then you can serialize your header and body message using 
a `DataOutputStream`, but I would suggest investigating Protocol Buffers as well.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I am totally new to Protocol Buffers. If possible can you provide an example basis on my solution and by that I will be able to understand how to use protocol buffers on my example.

Comment: @user2809564 Please see my updated answer for an example for your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `DataOutputStream` that is targeted to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. When you're done with writing the message to the DataOutputStream, you can obtain the constructed byte array from the ByteArrayOutputStream.

Like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);
dos.writeInt(client_id);
dos.writeUTF(data_center);
// etc...
byte[] message = baos.toByteArray();
```

Protocol Buffers are also a good option, if you want more flexibility and higher performance. It depends on what you want to get out of this application; if it needs higher performance, or whether it's a one-off throwaway app or something that you expect to grow and be maintained in the longer future. DataOutputStream and DataInputStream are simple to use and you can start right away, you need to invest a bit more of your time to learn Protocol Buffers.

Comment: Thanks for example, How does my C++ application will decode this? They need to know what are the bytes we have written first right? Just trying to understand the process? And where will I add my actual message? It should be after the header values. can you add an example for that as well if possible? Still learning few things related to byte array and how to use it.